# Extract the value of mpmath.gamma in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, mpmath, gamma-function

The output of mpmath.gamma in python function prints the values in this way like:

```
mpf('1.7780824344856125e-342')
```

How to extract the value or just printing the value like this:

```
y=1.7780824344856125e-342
```

if I use float(y) it gives zero.

Answer (score 1):

For me this is working fine:

```
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 10 # not really necessary...
smallValue = mp.mpf('1.7780824344856125e-342')
print(f"As a mp.mpf value: {smallValue}")
smallValueStr = mp.nstr(smallValue)
print(f"As a string: "+smallValueStr)
```

Results:

```
As a mp.mpf value: 1.778082434e-342
As a string: 1.77808e-342
```

Now I am not sure if you can represent this kind of value as a floating point. It has to do with the limits of these data types. For more reference, check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Tino D the issue is that `1.77808e-342` is smaller than the smallest positive double precision float (the default python floating number container). You can check it with the [numpy utils](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.tiny.html):

```py
np.finfo(np.float64).tiny
# 2.2250738585072014e-308
```

which explains why it gets rounded down to `0`. There are no double numbers between `0` and `~1e-308` and your very tiny number sits in that interval. When you cast it to a double, it gets "rounded down" to `0`, hence your observation.

Comment: I like your answer more than mine, well explained!